# Using an array in InStr

Tags: vba, excel, match

I am looking for a vba code for finding out if an array of strings is contained(not totally matched) in the cells of a column. I have a list of fake emails stored in the sheet "Helper" on A1:A3242 and in sheet JP i have the list of emails(I:I) I want to check.

If an email from the first list is found in the 2nd column i need the row to be colored in yellow.

```
Dim list As Variant, FF As Long, qq As Long

list = Sheets("Helper").Range("A1:A3242").Value
FF = Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For qq = 1 To FF
    If InStr(1, list, cell.Value) <> 0 Then
        Range("I" & qq).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next qq

End Sub
```

I am really new to VBA and i don't know if this the correct approach, I am getting error "424 Object required", Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You haven't declared your variable `cell`.  (That's why you get an "object required" error - only an object or a user-defined-type will have something like `.Value` after the variable name.)  But you also won't be able to perform an `Instr` on an array.

Comment: The answer will probably be using `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(qq, "I").Value, list, 0)) Then`, but I'm not an export on `Match` so I'll let someone else answer.

Comment: @YowE3K is that a hint ? ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado A hint of the form "here's something that **might** work, but I am too tired and lazy to actually test it to ensure that I don't embarrass myself by posting it as an answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Function GetDomain(s as String) as String
Dim x as Integer
X = instr(s,"@")
If x=0 then
     GetDomain = s
Else
     GetDomain = right(s,len(s)-x)
End IF
End Function
```

Then wrap your string around this function:

```
     If Not IsError(Application.Match(GetDomain(.Range("I" & qq).Value), list, 0))
```

(Should work, not tested)

Comment: Thank You! It works. I was just thinking the same, adding a column where i just trim whats after @ and use the previous code to check exact match but this works. Thank You again :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Application.Match` function, see code below (explanations inside the code's comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchEmailList()

Dim list As Variant, FF As Long, qq As Long

list = Sheets("Helper").Range("A1:A3242").Value

With Sheets("JP") ' fully qualify the sheet
    FF = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column "I" from sheet "JP"

    For qq = 1 To FF
        ' if not is Error >> Match was successful to find a match
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("I" & qq).Value, list, 0)) Then
            .Rows(qq).Interior.Color = vbRed ' color entire roe in red
        End If
    Next qq
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look over this, I tried to use this method but unfortunately it colors only the exact matches and I would need to find the "@test.com" in "john.smith@test.com".

Comment: @CalinLencar aren't the emails strings exactly the same on both sheets ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I would need to find the "@test.com" in "john.smith@test.com".